# (4 + sub) not equals to (sub + 4)?

Tags: perl, winapi, operator-precedence

**(edit) TL;DR**: my problem was that I though the Win32 API defines were true integer *constants* (as in the platform SDK headers) while the Win32 Perl wrapper defines them as *subs*. Thus caused the one-liner parsing misunderstood.

---

While testing in a one-liner a call to `Win32::MsgBox`, I am puzzled by the following : giving that the possible arguments for `MsgBox` are the message, a sum of flags to chose the kind of buttons (value 0..5) and message box icon "constants" (`MB_ICONSTOP`, ...) and the title

calling `perl -MWin32 -e"Win32::MsgBox world, 4+MB_ICONQUESTION, hello"` gives the expected result

[image: OK]

while the looking similar code `perl -MWin32 -e"Win32::MsgBox world, MB_ICONQUESTION+4, hello"` is wrong

[image: NOK]

I first though that it comes from my lack of parenthesis, but adding some `perl -MWin32 -e"Win32::MsgBox (world, MB_ICONQUESTION+4, hello)"` gives exactly the same wrong result.

I tried with a colleague to dig deeper and display the parameters that are passed to a function call (as the `MB_xxx` constants are actually subs) with the following code

```
>perl -Mstrict -w -e"sub T{print $/,'called T(#'.join(',',@_).'#)'; 42 }; print $/,'results:', join ' ,', T(1), T+1, 1+T"
```

that outputs

```
called T(#1#)
called T(##)
called T(#1,43#)
results:42 ,42
```

but I can't understand why in the list passed to `join()` the args `T+1, 1+T` are parsed as `T(1, 43)`...

Comment: The downvote on this question is clearly wrong. This is a valid question about somewhat confusing subroutine and operator precedence.

Comment: It is interesting that you call `MB_ICONQUESTION` a constant, but then experiment with subroutines. The title of your question should indicate subroutines, not constants.

Comment: @TLP: my monk colleague pointed me that `MB_ICONQUESTION` was actually a sub (as constants are usually subs in perl) so we tried the later test. i will change the title

Comment: also, i am familiar with true C `MB_xx` defines from win32 api

Comment: Looking at it - the `Win32` module doesn't use a constant, it defines it via `sub`. Which is - deep down - why this problem exists in the first place.

Comment: (And as a random comment - there's been several really interesting questions recently. I like good questions, so thank you).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the `Deparse` package to help for understanding how perl is reading my code!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`B::Deparse` to the rescue:

```
C:>perl -MO=Deparse -MWin32 -e"Win32::MsgBox world, MB_ICONQUETION+4, hello"
use Win32;
Win32::MsgBox('world', MB_ICONQUESTION(4, 'hello'));
-e syntax OK

C:>perl -MO=Deparse -MWin32 -e"Win32::MsgBox world, 4+MB_ICONQESTION, hello"
use Win32;
Win32::MsgBox('world', 4 + MB_ICONQUESTION(), 'hello');
-e syntax OK
```

The `MB_ICONQUESTION` call in the first case is considered a function call with the arguments `+4, 'hello'`. In the second case, it is considered as a function call with no arguments, and having 4 added to it. It is not a constant, it seems, but a function.

In the source code we get this verified:

```
sub MB_ICONQUESTION                     { 0x00000020 }
```

It is a function that returns `32` (`00100000` in binary, indicating a bit being set). Also as [Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique) points out, this is a flag variable, so you should not use addition, but the bitwise logical and/or operators.

In your case, it just accepts any arguments and ignores them. This is a bit confusing if you are expecting a constant.

In your experiment case, the statement

```
print $/,'results:', join ' ,', T(1), T+1, 1+T
```

Is interpreted

```
print $/,'results:', join ' ,', T(1), T(+1, (1+T))
```

Because execution from right to left goes

```
1+T = 43
T +1, 43 = 42
T(1) = 42
```

Because plus `+` has higher [precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) than comma `,`, and unary `+` even higher.

To disambiguate, you need to do use parentheses to clarify precedence:

```
print $/,'results:', join ' ,', T(1), T()+1, 1+T
#                                      ^^-- parentheses
```

As a general rule, one should always use parentheses with subroutine calls. In [`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) there are 4 calling notations:

```
NAME(LIST);    # & is optional with parentheses.
NAME LIST;     # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
&NAME(LIST);   # Circumvent prototypes.
&NAME;         # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
```

Of which *in my opinion*, only the first one is transparent, and the other ones a bit obscure.

Comment: Ultimately a bug in the module providing the "constant", that it forgot to give the '()' prototype which exists to solve exactly this problem.

Comment: Or just `use constant` which I think handles it properly too.

Comment: @LeoNerd Prototypes are more often the problem than the solution. They exist to give the possibility to make subroutines act like built-ins, not for argument checking.

Comment: @TLP I'm well aware of that. The () prototype is one of the rare few that *does* make sense to use in modern code. Specifically, it tells the /parser/ "this function never takes an argument", so that  `CONSTANT+ 1`  would be parsed as  `CONSTANT() + 1` instead of, in its absence, `CONSTANT(+1)`. This question is the exact circumstance that prototype is for.

Answer (score 5):

This is all to do with how you're invoking `T` and how perl is interpreting the results.

If we deparse your example we get:

```
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
sub T {
    use strict;
    print $/, 'called T(#' . join(',', @_) . '#)';
    42;
}
use strict;
print $/, 'results:', join(' ,', T(1), T(1, 1 + T()));
```

This is clearly not what you've got in mind, but does explain why you get the result you do.

I would suggest in your *original* example - rather that `+` you may wish to consider using `|` as it looks very much like `MB_ICONQUESTION` is intended to be a flag.

So:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32 qw( MB_ICONQUESTION );

print MB_ICONQUESTION;

Win32::MsgBox( "world", 4 | MB_ICONQUESTION , "hello" );
```

Or

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32 qw( MB_ICONQUESTION );

print MB_ICONQUESTION;

Win32::MsgBox( "world", MB_ICONQUESTION | 4 , "hello" );
```

Produce the same result.

This is because of precence when invoking subroutines without brackets - you can do:

```
print "one", "two";
```

And both are treated as arguments to `print`. Perl *assumes* that arguments after a `sub` are to be passed to it.

`+4` is enumerated as an argument, and passed to `T`.

```
sub test { print @_,"\n";};

test 1;
test +1;
```

If we deparse this, we see perl treats it as:

```
test 1;
test 1;
```

So ultimately - there is a bug in Win32 that you have found, that would be fixable by:

```
sub MB_ICONQUESTION() {0x00000020}

Win32::MsgBox "world", 4 + MB_ICONQUESTION, "hello";
Win32::MsgBox "world", MB_ICONQUESTION + 4, "hello";
```

Or perhaps:

```
use constant MB_ICONQUESTION => 0x00000020;
```

Or as noted - the workaround in your code - don't use `+` and instead use `|` which is going to have the same result for bit flag operations, but because of operator precedence is never going to be passed into the subroutine. (Or of course, always specify the parenthesis for your constants)

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use binary `OR` instead of the addition, btw, I did not think about using explicit parenthesis because at first I did not know that the API constant was not actually a constant but a sub... I am kinda a Perl newcomer :o)

Comment: Everyone starts a language at the beginning. You put together an excellent question there, which is much appreciated - interesting and with enough depth to reproduce and investigate.